# PHP mail utf-8 issues

Tags: php, email, encoding, utf-8, postfix-mta

I've trying to send an email in `utf-8` encoding using a PHP mail() func. And there's some issues with this. Such as:

1. If in a body of email is present the unicode characters then I receive
   an email with header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream".
   Otherwise, if there was no unicode chars I've got `Content-Type:
   text/plain; charset=us-ascii`. This behavior is not depending of
   sending a header `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`
2. If the subject consists of `utf-8` chars that encoded according to
   RFC2047 then I receive a double encoded subject like this `Subject:
   =?us-ascii?Q?=3D=3FUTF-8=3FB=3Fw5HClsORwpfDkcKU=3F=3D?=`.
   Instead of expected `Subject: =?UTF-8?B?w5HClsORwpfDkcKU?=`

Example:

```
$subject = 'іїє';
$body = 'іїє';
$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
    . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

mail('some-address@gmail.com', mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, 'UTF-8', 'B'), $body, $headers);
```

Here is the part of received headers:

```
Subject: =?us-ascii?Q?=3D=3FUTF-8=3FB=3Fw5HClsORwpfDkcKU=3F=3D?=
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 6/20/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

С–С—С”
```

As MTA on server is installed postfix.
As a client using gmail

Comment: Seriously, instead of trying to work around all the limitations of the built-in `mail()` function you should just use a decent mailer class like [phpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [Swiftmailer](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer). You'll save yourself a whole lot of hassle and frustration.

Comment: @Simba, thanks for your advice! But I'd interested of understanding the fundamental cause of this trouble))

Comment: If the charset is unicode and the encoding is UTF8, have you specified both?  Have you tried a charset like ISO 8859-2?  You can get php mail() to work, but you will have to be correct to the letter.  Expect a lot of test transmissions.  Until you break through the failure, it'll fail.  I don't think I've ever got it to work the way I wanted in less than 100 tries.  If you persist, then you'll probably make it.  You can do it.

Comment: @gladiola, sorry, i was wrong. I did mean charset but not encoding. Thanks for your suggestion. Now i've just fixed it in a text. But problem still the same

Comment: Did you look in example 8 of http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2047 ?  Near pages 10 to 12?  It looks like there is some advice in there about specifying a charset for values in the headers.

Comment: Maybe if you specify the charset you are using in the headers, it'll go better.  Something like " To: =?ISO-8859-2?" followed by some values that specify each character might lean toward a solution.

Comment: The problem is in replacing of ANY content of the subject field by =?us-ascii?Q?<any-content-recoded-by-quated-printable>?=. In other words, some part of infrastructure of mail delivering rejects the headers are sending and considering them as raw content. Doesn't matter what kind is it. Why it's happening?

Comment: It looks like the headers that passing to the mail() func are rejected at all

Comment: PHP MAN for mail() http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php: to a note on headers http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html states, "A field name MUST be composed of printable US-ASCII characters".

Comment: On second thought, you may be providing that.  Throughout that reference, there are many referrals to ASCII.  Maybe by plinking between the MAN pages and the RFCs you'll find it.

Comment: Of course! In compliance to this requirement it's need to be encoded by one of two ways - "quoted printable" or "base64" algorithm which reflects the original alphabet into destination alphabet (us-ascii). But problem in rejection of already encoded content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is a very archaic, outdated, and difficult technology. This is especially true with character encoding. I would suggest using a library, such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). If you insist upon doing this from scratch, the true answer will go beyond the scope of your question. Browsers, clients, and much more complicate this issue. I can't tell you the cause of your issue, but the solution is PHPMailer.